# In Magento 2.2, How to Place the order after GrandTotal is Rs. 0?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods, grand-total

I have added custom **Checkbox** under Payment section in Checkout Page for My **WalletAmount**. When i click the checkbox wallet amount is added in totals section and calculated with GrandTotal **(Grandtotal = Grandtotal - Walletamount)**. After applying WalletAmount, **GrandTotal** is **Rs.0.00**. Same time when i click my checkbox, i have **Customly Refreshed Payment Section**. Now I am getting a message (**No Payment Information Required**). Then, When i Place the Order, I am getting the ErrorMessage **The requested Payment Method is not available.**

```
How to Place the Order using WalletAmount when GrandTotal is Rs.0.00 ?
```

Comment: How you are reducing your grandtotal to 0 amount?

Comment: Using this                                                                                                     
           $total->setBaseGrandTotal(round($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $total->getBasWalletAmount()), 0);

Comment: After that you are using `CollectTotal()` ?

Comment: Yes bro using CollectTotals() function

Comment: Please help me?